# C# Wrong conversion using Convert.ChangeType()

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I am using Convert.ChangeType() to convert from Object (which I get from DataBase) to a generic type T. The code looks like this:

```
T element = (T)Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(T));
return element;
```

and this works great most of the time, however I have discovered that if I try to cast something as simple as return of the following sql query

```
select 3.2
```

the above code (T being double) wont return 3.2, but 3.2000000000000002. I can't realise why this is happening, or how to fix it. Please help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're seeing is an artifact of the way floating-point numbers are represented in memory. There's quite a bit of information available on exactly why this is, but [this paper](http://www.physics.ohio-state.edu/~dws/grouplinks/floating_point_math.pdf) is a good one. This phenomenon is why you can end up with seemingly anomalous behavior. A `double` or `single` should never be displayed to the user unformatted, and you should avoid equality comparisons like the plague.

If you need numbers that are accurate to a greater level of precision (ie, representing currency values), then use `decimal`.

Answer (score 4):

This probably is because of [floating point arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point). You probably should use decimal instead of double.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a problem of Convert. Internally double type represent as infinite fraction of 2 of real number, that is why you got such result. Depending of your purpose use:

- Either Decimal
- Or use precise formating {0:F2}
- Use Math.Flor/Math.Ceil